# concatenating non repeating element with repeating element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tibco

I have the below sample source XML data. now i need to get the output
 in such a way that each serial number has to be printed with its productNo value conactinated by pipe symbol with the help of XSLT.

```
<orders>
    <orderItems>
        <productNo>500656-B21</productNo>
        <serialNumber>KRW13707EV</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9137RFRV</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9137RFRW</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9137RFRX</serialNumber>
    </orderItems>
   <orderItems>
        <productNo>500686-B21</productNo>
        <serialNumber>KRW13807EZ</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9138RFRD</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9138RFRY</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9138RF51</serialNumber>
    </orderItems>
   <orderItems>
        <productNo>500693-B26</productNo>
        <serialNumber>KRW139075V</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9139RFXV</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9139RFW7</serialNumber>
        <serialNumber>PR9139RFZ5</serialNumber>
    </orderItems>
</orders>
```

Expected Output is:

```
<orders>
<serialNo>500656-B21|KRW13707EV</serialNo>
<serialNo>500656-B21|PR9137RFRV</serialNo>
<serialNo>500656-B21|PR9137RFRW</serialNo>
<serialNo>500656-B21|PR9137RFRX</serialNo>
<serialNo>500686-B21|KRW13807EZ</serialNo>
<serialNo>500686-B21|PR9138RFRD</serialNo>
<serialNo>500686-B21|PR9138RFRY</serialNo>
<serialNo>500686-B21|PR9138RF51</serialNo>
<serialNo>500693-B26|KRW139075V</serialNo>
<serialNo>500693-B26|PR9139RFXV</serialNo>
<serialNo>500693-B26|PR9139RFW7</serialNo>
<serialNo>500693-B26|PR9139RFZ5</serialNo>
</orders>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="orders">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="orderItems/serialNumber"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="serialNumber">
  <serialNo>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(../productNo, '|', .)"/>
  </serialNo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

should suffice.